# hornetq divert with message expiration not honored

Tags: jms, hornetq

If i have a divert configured in hornetq (from a topic to a queue), i'd like it to honor any TTL set on the message. It doesn't appear to be the case "by default". Message expiration is ignored in this case.

If i send to a queue directly, the ttl is honored.

Is there a way to make this happen dynamically? Or even statically (by some config on the divert)?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to provide a transformer class using `<transformer-class-name>` property of the divert to re-set the ttl. A transformer class can be implemented as below.

```
public class YourTransformer implements Transformer {
 public ServerMessage transform(final ServerMessage message)
   {
      //your code;
   }    
}
```

For a sample implementation look under default HornetQ samples shipped with the HornetQ server.